# Unable to install SonarLint.vsix in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express, sonarlint

I am trying to install Sonar Qube extension in VS 2015 Express for Desktop version. When I am trying to open it by double click or open with -> VS version selector, it is throwing me error :

```
28.10.2015 13:07:27 - Searching for applicable products...
28.10.2015 13:07:27 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop
28.10.2015 13:07:27 - Found installed product - Global Location
28.10.2015 13:07:27 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What can be the probable reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express only supports a (very) limited set of extensions, generally only those shipped by Microsoft themselves.

Luckily they released Visual Studio Community Edition, which you may be abllowed to use instead. This version is almost up to par with the full Professional edition of Visual Studio.

You could also register SonarLint in you project as a Nuget Package Analyzer, that should just work for Visual Studio Express 2015.

Comment: This means that I will not be able to use this sonarlint extension with Express for Desktop Version, right?

Comment: Correct, only the nuget version i suspect.